# Populate a listbox using a loop while ignoring blanks

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am trying to populate a listbox using items in column P and I would like to ignore the blanks.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim strItem As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 500

        If Cells(i, 16).Value = "" Then

        Else
            strItem = Selection.Value
            Debug.Print strItem
            lbxItems.AddItem strItem.Value

        End If


End Sub
```

When I populate the listbox it all shows as blank. I expected it to be populated with the items in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually change the selection in your code. You are expecting this line to be at `P(i)`, but it remains at whatever you happen to have selected when kicking off the macro:

```
strItem = Selection.Value
```

To show this, add this line just inside the `FOR`loop:

```
Debug.Print Selection.Address
```

To fix this, change the way you select the cell:

```
strItem = Cells(i, 16).Value
```

Your sub should now be:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim strItem As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 10
        '' Debugging only:
        '' Debug.Print Selection.Address
        If Cells(i, 16).Value <> "" Then
            strItem = Cells(i, 16).Value
            Debug.Print strItem
            lbxItems.AddItem strItem
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Note that I've also changed what gets added to the listbox (as `{string}.value` is invalid) and reversed the `IF` to prevent the empty `true`-block .